# Обособление сравнительного оборота (здесь есть варианты?)

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Можно не обособлять оборот, правилами допускается? А как лучше?

(1) *Туман **как огромное море** затопил все земные пространства.*

(2) *Государство **как и раньше** остается главным регулятором экономических реформ.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Туман как огромное мОре затопил все земные пространства.*
Для такого ударения часть после оборота должна быть короткой. В первом примере длинновато, но с натяжкой ещё можно, хотя читается не очень, а это указывает на проблемы со стилистикой.
Для такой пунктуации "*все земные пространства*" должно быть без ударения, а оно пафосное, из-за чего ударение просится. Не стоит говорить "*все земные пространства*", потому что это подразумевает всю планету.
Правка: *Туман как огромное мОре всё вокруг затопил.*

Частица И формирует сравнительный оборот, из-за неё во втором примере так не получается. Да и часть после оборота слишком длинная. "*Как и раньше*" требует обособления, оно не годится для первого плана, о котором сказано у Розенталя.

В любом случае ясно, что такая позиция оборота характерна и удобна для обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Как и раньше – это сравнительный оборот в роли обстоятельства. Какие проблемы?  Разницы нет между предложениями.

Comment: Здесь точно нельзя из-за И и длины части после оборота. Найдите у Розенталя хоть один пример с И. У него про обороты с И отдельно говорится. Эта информация не для первого плана. Здесь точно знаю, иначе бы не стал спорить. Пока не знаю, как обосновать влияние И. Это не просто.

Comment: Здесь все как и прежде. Нет запятой.

Comment: Но здесь сказуемое, а не обстоятельство.

Comment: Ещё один момент. Для такой пунктуации "все земные пространства" должно быть без ударения, а оно пафосное, из-за чего ударение просится. Так что правка нужна ещё из-за этого.

Comment: Изменил предложенный вариант для лучшей читаемости. Теперь оно звучит сравнимо с примерами Розенталя (в плане соотношения частей). Как ни странно, а в этой теме важен ритм фразы, без этого здесь никак. Ну и подправил ответ.

Comment: Туман как огромное мОре всё вокруг затопил.   НЕт, правка отклоняется. У автора все было идеально. (Ну, это мое мнение.)

Comment: Правка по части ритма, а не по части художественности.

Comment: У меня здесь не мнение, точно знаю) А то бы мимо прошёл.

Comment: Ну нет, oleedd. Может, вы и правы, но мне не нравится.

Comment: Пусть так, тогда замените на слова с похожим, а лучше одинаковым количеством слогов. На самом деле всё просто: часть после оборота должна быть очень краткой. Чем короче, тем лучше. Чем она длиннее, тем больше требуется дополнительное ударение.

Comment: Попробуйте в примеры Розенталя добавить И. Сразу запятые просятся.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий для oleedd**

Ну не люблю я ничего добавлять, переставлять и т.д.

**Это не мой метод**. У меня  все просто, так что младший школьник поймет.

(1) Туман **как огромное мОре** //затопил все земные пространства. ТумАн, **как огромное мОре** //затопил все земные пространства.

(2)  Государство **как и рАньше** //остается главным регулятором/ экономических реформ. ГосудаАрство, **как и рАньше,** //остается главным регулятором/ экономических реформ.

Мы видим, что оба предложения имеют **по два интонационных варианта** (простое предложение и предложение с обособлением).

И вот вариант простого предложения выглядит **более художественным и выразительным** в первом примере, а во втором примере логическим ударением **подчеркнуто** «как и прежде». (Я полагаю, что это соответствует основной  мысли автора.)

Answer (score 0):

*Туман, как огромное море, хлынувшее вдруг из ущелий гор, затопил все земные контуры*. [Г.Федосеев. Мы идём по Восточному Саяну](https://booksonline.com.ua/view.php?book=36507&page=4)

***Туман, как огромное море, затопил все земные пространства***. - Обычный сравнительный оборот, сравниваются 2 объекта - туман и море, один объект уподобляется другому (*подобно морю*). Обособляем.

***Государство, как и раньше, остается главным регулятором экономических реформ.***

Выражение "как и раньше" по значению и структуре приближено к придаточному сравнительному (ср.: *как это было  и раньше*). Обособляем.

Comment: А что, так и будем – сравнивать и списывать, списывать и сравнивать? Ну чтобы все одинаковым было?  Ваша формальная позиция мне предельно ясна, это ваш шаблон-образец.  Для ответа на ЕГЭ подходит безусловно.  Но не подходит для художественной литературы в целом.  Читайте чаще Розенталя (его предисловие) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php – может, поймете наконец, о чем он там говорит. Кроме того, вы не пользуетесь струтурно-интонационным анализом, а было бы хорошо, если  бы вы  освоили этот метод. Иначе мне сложно обсуждать с вами эту тему.

Comment: Sharon, надо обладать несомненными достоинствами, чтобы позволять себе такой тон (..."может, поймете наконец, о чем он там говорит"). Осторожно, не упадите с уровня вашего самомнения!